# tmux: variables sharing between sessions

Tags: tmux

I've noticed that

1. `tmux` will share variable between sessions.
2. `tmux` will increment `TMUX_PANE` for new session as well.

Is it possible to reset `VAR` for each session?

Is it possible to start `TMUX_PANE` from `0` for each session?

```
# set variable
# create 2 sessions
$ export VAR=aaaaa
$ tmux new -A -s $VAR -d

$ export VAR=bbbbb
$ tmux new -A -s $VAR -d

$ tmux ls
aaaaa: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 23 12:12:46 2015) [207x50]
bbbbb: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 23 12:12:55 2015) [207x50]

# connect to sessions
# check value of variable
$ tmux att -t aaaaa
$ echo $VAR
aaaaa

$ tmux att -t bbbbb
$ echo $VAR
aaaaa            <-------- i would like to see 'bbbbb' here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found workaround.

Multiple servers with `-L` option (which specifies socket name).

```
# set variable
# create 2 sessions
$ export VAR=aaaaa
$ tmux -L $VAR new -A -s $VAR -d

$ export VAR=bbbbb
$ tmux -L $VAR new -A -s $VAR -d

$ tmux ls
failed to connect to server
$ tmux -L aaaaa ls
aaaaa: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 23 12:12:46 2015) [207x50]
$ tmux -L bbbbb ls
bbbbb: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 23 12:12:55 2015) [207x50]

# connect to sessions
# check value of variable
$ tmux -L aaaaa att -t aaaaa
$ echo $VAR
aaaaa

$ tmux -L bbbbb att -t bbbbb
$ echo $VAR
bbbbb            <-------- now i can see 'bbbbb' here
```